# Tired light hypothesis question deriving the distance redshift relation

Tags: cosmology

I need to find that distance(r) and redhshift(z) gives a linear relationship for $z<<1$ in tired light hypothesis and find the K value for the Hubble constant of $H=70 km s^{-1} Mpc^{-1}$

I kind of couldnt derive the relationship between $z$ and $r$

The equation of energy and distance can be written as,

$$dE/dr=-KE$$ or we get $$E(r)=e^{-Kr}+C$$

since energy is Equal to $E=hc/ \lambda$ we can write

$$hc/ \lambda=e^{-Kr}+C$$ lets say $C=0$ then we have

$$\lambda(r)=hc~e^{Kr}$$

so for distance r the wavelenght increases by the amount of $hc~e^{Kr}$

and redshift is defined as $$z=\lambda_o/ \lambda_e -1$$

or in this case

$$z=(\lambda_e+hc~e^{Kr})/ \lambda_e -1$$

and hence we have

$$z=hc~e^{Kr}/\lambda_e$$

Is this true ?

And maybe any ideas how can I pass from here to Hubble Constant ?

I thought that maybe we can use real examples. Like a real galaxy with redshift value z and distance r we can find K and that K value will correspond to Hubble constant for H=70 since in our world Hubble constant is 70. (The writer of the book took the Hubble constant as 70)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just want to improve on something, the solution can be written as

$$
E = E_0e^{-Kr} \tag{1}
$$

So the wavelength follows the relation

$$
\frac{hc}{\lambda} = \frac{hc}{\lambda_0}e^{-Kr} ~~~\Rightarrow~~~ \lambda = \lambda_0 e^{Kr} \tag{2}
$$

and from here it is easy to derive the redshift

$$
z = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda_0} - 1 = e^{Kr} - 1 ~~~\Rightarrow~~~ Kr = \ln(z + 1)=z - \frac{z^2}{2} + \frac{z^3}{3} \cdots\tag{3}
$$

For small redshift just take the leading term in the expression above

$$
Kr = z \tag{4}
$$

Which is just Hubble's Law with $\color{blue}{K = H_0/c}$

Comment: Thats nice I never thought that I can write the Energy in that form ($E=E_0e^{-Kr}$). I mean mathematically just writing $ln(E_0)$ instead of $C$...thats nice. Thanks

Comment: @ArthurMorgan Happy to help

Comment: How is expression (1) physically justified?

Comment: @Cham It's an *ad hoc* way for explaining redshift in a static universe

Comment: @caverac, so it has no physical support?  This is weirder than assuming an evolving universe.  Feel like "magic" to my eyes.  ;-)

Comment: @Cham it is a model, hence the name ‘hypothesis’. It reproduces observations at small redshift, so if you think about it (even knowing it is fundamentally wrong) it is kind of successful